# How to mock method in another class method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I got method in `notifier` file that i want to test:

```
def notify():
    Class_A.another_class_method()

Class A:
    @classmethod
    def prepare():
        helper_method()

    def another_class_method():
        prepare()
```

I need to mock helper_method.
How can i do this ?

I'm trying to patch it like:

```
with patch(
    'notifier.notify.Class_A.another_class_method.prepare.helper_method',
    return_value=True
)
```

but it is not works.

Comment: What you need to do is probably mock the `helper_method` from its original module, rather than from inside the call

Comment: Thank you for ur comment. But it is not works. Method is not Mocked after this.

Answer (score 0):

use `with patch("notifier.helper_method", return_value=True):`

Comment: Thank's for ur answer. But it is not works. AttributeError: <module 'notifier.helper_method.py'> does not have the attribute 'helper_method'

Comment: Could you can put your complete code and file structure here?